# NodeJS and Express: Check if request is for CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I have this set up at the start of my routes:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    req.xhr ? next() : res.render('layout/layout');
});
```

The thought is that if the request isn't XHR, return the base layout. The problem with this is that when the client requests JavaScript or CSS, the server returns the base layout. Is there some elegant way to know if the current request is for markup, and not other resources?

Or is there a better solution to this problem? Basically I need the base layout returned if the request isn't XHR and is asking for .html (markup). I actually have .jade files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the `express.static()` middleware above that route you should be fine.